# AVG() inside LISTAGG()

Tags: sql, oracle18c

I need to group two columns, one of them with an average, AVG() inside an LISTAGG().
I have the following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW countryTimes AS 
SELECT
  LISTAGG(claOL.odCode||'-'||(AVG(claOL.timeCla) GROUP BY(claOl.timeCla))) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.cCode) AS ProvaTempsMig,
  c.cDescription AS País,
  c.cCode AS CodiPaís
FROM countries c 
JOIN athletes a ON c.cCode = a.country 
JOIN classificationOL claOL ON a.idCode = claOL.idAth;
```

But this throws this error:

ORA-00907: missing right parenthiesis erecho 00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis" *Cause:     *Action:

I'm using Oracle.

UPDATE:
What I need to do is create a view where appears cCode, cDescription and a last column with the AVG of all the times for a single country. So I need to create from multiple rows, a single row for each country.

Code:

```
    CREATE TABLE Countries (
cCode VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
cdescription VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT couPK PRIMARY KEY (cCode)
);
CREATE TABLE athletes (
idCode NUMBER NOT NULL,
Name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
Surname VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
country VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT athPK PRIMARY KEY (idCode),
CONSTRAINT countryFK FOREIGN KEY (country) REFERENCES Countries (cCode)
);
CREATE TABLE olympicDisciplines (
oCode VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
odName VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
discipline VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT olympicPK  PRIMARY KEY (oCode)
);
CREATE TABLE classificationOL(
idAth NUMBER NOT NULL,
odCode VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
timeCla INTEGER,
CONSTRAINT classifPK PRIMARY KEY (idAth, odCode),
CONSTRAINT claAthFK FOREIGN KEY (idAth) REFERENCES athletes (idCode),
CONSTRAINT claDFK FOREIGN KEY (odCode) REFERENCES olympicDisciplines (oCode)
);
```

UPDATE 2:
Data:

```
INSERT INTO Countries VALUES ('UK', 'United Kingdom');
INSERT INTO Countries VALUES ('AND', 'Andorra');
INSERT INTO Countries VALUES ('FR', 'France');
INSERT INTO athletes VALUES (1, 'Jack', 'Johnson', 'UK');
INSERT INTO athletes VALUES (2, 'Pau', 'Márquez', 'AND');
INSERT INTO athletes VALUES (3, 'Pierre', 'Dubois', 'FR');
INSERT INTO athletes VALUES (4, 'Christophe', 'Dubois', 'FR');
INSERT INTO athletes VALUES (5, 'Adolphe', 'Moreau', 'FR');
INSERT INTO olympicDisciplines VALUES ('ATH', 'Athletics', 'Athletics');
INSERT INTO olympicDisciplines VALUES ('CYC', 'Cycling', 'Cycling');
INSERT INTO olympicDisciplines VALUES ('CCC', 'Cycling CC', 'Cross Country Cycling');
INSERT INTO classificationOL VALUES (1, 'ATH', 120);
INSERT INTO classificationOL VALUES (2, 'ATH', 119);
INSERT INTO classificationOL VALUES (3, 'CCC', 38);
INSERT INTO classificationOL VALUES (4, 'CCC', 37);
INSERT INTO classificationOL VALUES (5, 'ATH', 122);
```

Comment: Please provide the tables structure and sample data [mre]

Comment: `LISTAGG()` combines multiple ROWS into a single value, are you sure you don't just want `CONCAT()` to combine two scalar values into a single string?  Then, you can't specify a `GROUP BY` in the middle of the `SELECT` clause. If you create an example (as per the comment above), then we can see both the starting data and the required results, and help you with the code to accomplish it. At present we can only see faulty code, no understanding of what you intended to achieve, no idea of the data you're dealing with, and no idea of the results you want.

Comment: We need example data. Not just table definitions. Think in terms of unit tests.

Comment: Provide a few rows (minimum required) of data, and provide the _precise_ result you wish to generate, given that specific test data.

Comment: @MatBailie updated with some data, sorry.

Comment: And the expected results given that specific example data?

Comment: Just as an aside, the following expression must be a typo, since one of the table qualifiers doesn't exist.  If they are intended to be the same table qualifier, the `AVG(term)` of the `GROUP BY term`, will always be the `term` value, which could be `null`...  `AVG(claOL.timeCla) GROUP BY(claOl.timeCla)` .. ignoring for the moment that this usage is invalid.  Conceptually, that average calculation (even if in an acceptable form) seems to be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your first UPDATE, if you're allowed to, you can transform your tables to object to solve your necessity, instead of using LISTAGG(). I'll show you:

```
CREATE TYPE average AS OBJECT( 
name VARCHAR(200), 
avgerageTime NUMBER);

CREATE TYPE results AS TABLE OF average;

CREATE TYPE countriesResults AS OBJECT( 
cName VARCHAR(100), 
cCode VARCHAR(5), 
classifications results
);

CREATE VIEW countriesAverages OF countriesResults 
WITH OBJECT OID (coName) 
AS 
SELECT c.cdescription, c.ccode, 
CAST (MULTISET (SELECT 
olympicDisciplines.name, avg(classificationOL.timeCla) 
FROM athletes a, countries, classificationOL, olympicDisciplines 
WHERE countries.cCode = c.cCode 
AND a.idCode = classificationOL.idAth 
AND a.country = countries.cCode 
AND olympicdisciplines.oCode = classificationOL.oCode 
GROUP BY olympicdisciplines.odName) AS results ) 
FROM countries c;
```

Comment: It's working now, thank you so much. But do you know if there's a way to do the same using LISTAGG()? I would like to do it without using objects. Thanks.

Comment: @Gilet the thing here is that `LISTAGG()` is used to aggregate different columns in one, and what you need to do is aggregate different rows in one. So in this case, I think `LISTAGG()` isn't the best option for what you need.